# django check post expiry function

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie and i am trying to build an function that checks to see the listing expiry. If it's expired, I want the in_progress booleanfield=False.

What are my options? I couldn't find any smart way to do that. Please help.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    in_progress = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to do exactly. From your question, I understand that maybe:

1. You want to add a method on the instance that set `in_progress` to `False` given some conditions?
2. You want to make a function that goes through all `Post` objects and sets `in_progress` to `False` on those that meet some conditions?
3. You want to make such a function and have it run periodically?
4. You want to have some conditions checked at specific moments (object loading / object saving) and update `in_progress` depending on those?
5. You do not really need to have an `in_progress` field at all and you could set up a read-only property that returns `True` or `False` based on some conditions?

The easiest option, if you do not need to be able to do DB query on the field, is to just remove it entirely and let it be a computed property, like this:

```
@property
def in_progress(self):
    return self.expiration_date > timezone.now()
```

(timezone being the `django.utils.timezone` module)

Comment: Hi, I wanted it to be able to check constantly that it will hide the post once the in_progress=False, basically I only want the post exist for a period of time.

Comment: Alright. Do you need to be able to query it? Like, do you need to be able to do `Post.objects.filter(in_progress=True)`, or is it okay to do `Post.objects.filter(expiration_date__gt=timezone.now())`?

Comment: Yes,that would be better to sort out all the inactive posts.

Comment: Well, both queries will get you all the inactive posts. The difference is in how this knowledge is acquired. In the first case, that knowledge is external: *something* must update the db regularly, probably some equivalent to a cron job. In the second case, the knowledge is internal: it looks up expired objects because it knows how to find them given their date.

Comment: the duration is how many days the creator wants the post to stay active

Comment: Then just remove the `in_progress` field, and compare `expiration_date` to current time. `Post.objects.filter(expiration_date__gt=timezone.now())` does exactly this: it retrieves only objects whose expiration date is still in the future.

Comment: I get it now. is there a way to sort it in the admin with that?

Comment: You can set a [custom queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) in admin. But that's another topic :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this will work for you, although I have not tested it so there may be a typo.

So the situation is this, everytime a post is added or updated the save method gets called. the same method has some logic that will determine if the date is greater than today than it's expired so set the value to False.  This logic could be whatever date logic you need to take place to verify if the date is expired or not.

Django has a built in Save method that gets called on all it's model objects whenever they are written to the database.  This code below is an example of you overriding that save method for your class object.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    in_progress = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=15)

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
            ## your custom date logic to verify if expired or not.
            if self.expiration_date < datetime.datetime.now().date():
                self.in_progress = False
            super(Post, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: It works, but is there another way to check it constantly to see if it expires? I wanted it to hide itself once in_progress=False

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that in_progress is really a calculated value.  For purposes of this answer, I am going to assume that in_progress depends on the expiry date and the current date.  If the current date is after the expiry date, then the thing has expired and is no longer in progress.

So given that in_progress depends on something that is always known, but is not in the DB, I'm going to suggest that you don't put in_progress in the database but just calculate it at run time.  You can add a method on the Post class called in_progress and it can calculate the value of in_progress when it is called (i.e., when someone makes a request).